# ¿Cual es la función del charset dentro de los scriptlet en JSP?

Tags: html, netbeans, jsp

Verán, trabajando en mis proyectos me acabo de percatar que cuando uno crea un JSP en NetBeans, ademas del hecho de que te crea por defecto los charset de HTML4, crea también un charset dentro de scriptlet. ¿Es necesario que la información este repetida, tanto en la etiqueta  como en el scriptlet, o es posible dejar solo una?, ¿Para que sirve? (No me refiero al uso del charset en si, conozco la utilidad de codificación)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establecer el [código de caracteres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres) a usar en el documento html.
El código `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` es para el código java que se resuelve en el jsp que se ejecuta desde el servidor. El del meta es para el código html que se ejecuta en el cliente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta rápida y concisa.